# GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in

Tags: apt, package-management, plugins

I wrote a video player with Qt and when I tried to run it, this error occurred,

> Error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in"

This issue can be fixed by running the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

My question is, what happened after the installation? What things are installed in my computer? I'd like to find this missing plug-in so I can package it into my .deb. I think it must be a .so file, but I just don't know which one.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg -L gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` will tell you the package's contents. But since you're building your own deb, I would strongly recommend to specify gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg as a dependency, instead of packaging the plugin; if gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg is already installed, the installation of your package would fail since dpkg will refuse to overwrite the file (a single file can't be owned by more than one package).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should specify gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg as a dependency. But I'm afraid the users might not know how to use command line. Do you have any suggestions on this? So users don't need to install missing plugins themselves. I've benn confused about this for long

Comment: If you publish your package on a proper repositiory (Ubuntu's PPAs, or a personal repository you build from scratch), and if the user uses `apt-get` (or a front-end to it) to install your package, declaring `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` as a dependency will automatically install it when your package is installed.

Comment: Good call. Actually is there any way to install a deb that *doesn't* install its dependencies?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --install --force-depends <package>` but I wouldn't recommend it (and it needs the downloaded package, unlike `apt-get`). Plus, installation may abort with an error if some package needed as Pre-Depends is used in the preinst script, a situation that the [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html) discourages (_"It is best to avoid this situation if possible"_).